# Window form size adjustment

Tags: c#, forms, screen-size

I need to adjust my form according some size..I want that the form always will be half size of the screen, no matter what the size of the screen.

Always when I put some controller into the form and maximize/change the size of the form all the controllers get crazy and they are not in the order I put..

How can I know what the screen size..?

Comment: Unclear to me whether you are refering to WinForms, WPF or even WebForms or MVC.

Comment: aside from knowing the screen size,what probably happens to your controls is due to improper docking/anchoring....or some calculations you do in the Layout event maybe....more insight would be great,or else will be guess work :)

Comment: I talk about WinForms..I tried to use the anchor and dock option..it has not help me , When I resize the windows all the controlers move to other places

Answer (score 1):

To get the screen size:

```
Screen.FromControl(yourForm).Bounds;
```

or, if you only want the working area only (minus taskbar, docked toolbars, docked windows, etc.):

```
Screen.FromControl(yourForm).WorkingArea;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a class [Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8xzhd15.aspx) which you can use to get certain display information from. If you want to get the screen you can use:

```
Rectangle screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
```

and then from that you could get the height and width by doing:

```
int height = screen.Height;
int width = screen.Width;
```